# Cant resize navigation on top despite all tries

Tags: html, css, frameset

Could anyone help me out here?
I wanted to use a navigation frame on the top and load sites on the main frame below.

Everything works!

But I cant get it to scale properly if I minimize/resize the window to something other than full screen,

Tried CSS- margin, padding,used a complete new website without divs to try gain from scratch, set the frameset to relative size but the navigation disappears as soon as I minimize it despite all efforts,

**frameset on index.hmtl:**

```
<frameset rows="*,3*" cols="1"  framespacing="" frameborder="no" bordercolor="#D8D6DB">
   <frame src="menu.html" name="menu" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" >
   <frame src="home.html" name="main" frameborder="no" scrolling="yes" >
</frameset>
```

**navigation**

```
h1 id="logo"><a href="home.html" target="main">CFS ME Therapie</a></h1>

nav id="nav">                   


li>

li><a href="home.html" target="main">Startseite</a></li>

li><a href="therapie.html" target="main">Therapieansatz</a></li>

li><a href="leistungen.html" target="main">Leistungen</a></li>

li class="break"><a href="praxis.html" target="main">Praxis</a></li>

li><a href="qualifikation.html" target="main">Qualifikation</a></li>

li><a href="kontakt.html" target="main" >Kontakt</a></li>
```

**CSS**

/* Header */

```
#logo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 260px;
  margin-left: -7.5em;
}

#logo a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 4em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.35em 0.35em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: bold;
  alignment-adjust: middle;
  margin: auto;
}

#nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 4em;
}

#nav > ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

#nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
#nav > ul > li > span, #nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 0.35em;
  padding: 0.3em 1em 0.3em 1em;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out, background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out, background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out, background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out, background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out, background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav > ul > li.active > span, #nav > ul > li.active > a {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#nav > ul > li.break {
  margin-left: 20em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is broken. Also use of `<frame>` and `<frameset>` is deprecated.

You can read about responsive embeds [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/).

Answer (score 1):

`<frameset>` and responsive design are from different eras -- framesets are not just deprecated, they're officially "Non-conforming features" in HTML5, which "must not be used by authors": https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

I'm not sure exactly what the issue you're seeing is -- your HTML got mangled somehow so I can't check it, but I took a trip down nostalgia lane and tested out a frameset and it scaled just fine (according to its original proportional-to-viewport-ratio rules) everywhere I tested it. But whatever the problem is, is likely because browser makers aren't making much effort to support features which were obsoleted years ago.